# Reset kivy settings to original values

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am building an app and was wondering how to reset the kivy settings to their default values. Also, would it be possible to add a button that resets the settings to their default values. Here is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.settings import SettingsWithSidebar
from plyer.facades.storagepath import StoragePath
import plyer, json

settings_json = json.dumps([
    {'type': 'title',
     'title': 'example title'},
    {'type': 'bool',
     'title': 'A boolean setting',
     'desc': 'Boolean description text',
     'section': 'example',
     'key': 'boolexample'},
    {'type': 'numeric',
     'title': 'A numeric setting',
     'desc': 'Numeric description text',
     'section': 'example',
     'key': 'numericexample'},
    {'type': 'options',
     'title': 'An options setting',
     'desc': 'Options description text',
     'section': 'example',
     'key': 'optionsexample',
     'options': ['option1', 'option2', 'option3']},
    {'type': 'string',
     'title': 'A string setting',
     'desc': 'String description text',
     'section': 'example',
     'key': 'stringexample'},
    {'type': 'path',
     'title': 'Download Folder Path',
     'desc': "All downloaded manga will be found in this folder called 'manga_downloader_root' ",
     'section': 'example',
     'key': 'pathexample'}])

Builder.load_string('''
<Interface>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        text: 'open the settings!'
        font_size: 150
        on_release: app.open_settings()
        on_press: app.destroy_settings()
''')

class Interface(BoxLayout):
    pass

class SettingsApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.settings_cls = SettingsWithSidebar
        self.use_kivy_settings = False
        setting = self.config.get('example', 'pathexample')
        print(setting)
        print(plyer.storagepath.get_downloads_dir())
    
        return Interface()

    def build_config(self, config):
        user_downloads_dir = plyer.storagepath.get_downloads_dir()

        config.setdefaults('example', {
            'boolexample': True,
            'numericexample': 10,
            'optionsexample': 'option2',
            'stringexample': 'some_string',
            'pathexample': user_downloads_dir })

    def build_settings(self, settings):
        settings.add_json_panel('Panel Name', self.config, data=settings_json)
        
    def on_config_change(self, config, section, key, value):
        print (config, section, key, value)
if __name__ == "__main__":
   SettingsApp().run()
```

For more context, I am looking to make this app work on both android and PC. Would it also be possible to incorporate this code into a navigation bar which could be opened by an icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out a while ago, I will post a minimal answer for anyone who finds this. My solution uses this code from this [Github post](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Buttons-in-Settings-panel) .

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.settings import SettingItem, SettingsWithSpinner
import plyer, json

settings_json = json.dumps([
    {
        'type': 'title',
        'title': 'example title'
    },

    {
        'type': 'bool',
        'title': 'A boolean setting',
        'desc': 'Boolean description text',
        'section': 'example',
        'key': 'boolexample'
    },

    {
        'type': 'numeric',
        'title': 'A numeric setting',
        'desc': 'Numeric description text',
        'section': 'example',
        'key': 'numericexample'
     },

    {
        'type': 'options',
        'title': 'An options setting',
        'desc': 'Options description text',
        'section': 'example',
        'key': 'optionsexample',
        'options': ['option1', 'option2', 'option3'] 
    },

    {
        'type': 'string',
        'title': 'A string setting',
        'desc': 'String description text',
        'section': 'example',
        'key': 'stringexample'
    },

    {
        'type': 'path',
        'title': 'Download Folder Path',
        'desc': "All downloaded manga will be found in this folder called 'manga_downloader_root' ",
        'section': 'example',
        'key': 'pathexample'
    },

    # Added a button to reset the settings
    {
       "type":"buttons",
       "title":"Reset Settings",
       "desc":"Reset the settings to their default values",
       "section":"Settings",
       "key":"configchangebuttons",
       "buttons":[{"title":"Reset Settings", "id":"reset_settings_btn"}]
    }
         
])

class Interface(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Button(text="Open Settings", on_release=App.get_running_app().open_settings))

# Class to create a button-type settings item
class SettingButtons(SettingItem):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # For Python3 compatibility we need to drop the buttons keyword when calling super.
        kw = kwargs.copy()
        kw.pop('buttons', None)
        super(SettingItem, self).__init__(**kw)
        
        for aButton in kwargs["buttons"]:
            oButton=Button(text=aButton['title'], font_size= '15sp', on_release=self.on_button_press)
            oButton.ID=aButton['id']
            self.add_widget(oButton)
    
    def set_value(self, section, key, value):
        # set_value normally reads the configparser values and runs on an error (to do nothing here)
        return
    
    def on_button_press(self,instance):
        self.panel.settings.dispatch('on_config_change',self.panel.config, self.section, self.key, instance.ID)


class ScrollableSettings(SettingsWithSpinner):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.settings_types = [('buttons', SettingButtons)] # 'buttons' is the name of the settings type

        # Registers any new settings types
        for type_ in self.settings_types:
            self.register_type(*type_)


class SettingsApp(App):
    default_settings = {
            'boolexample': True,
            'numericexample': 10,
            'optionsexample': 'option2',
            'stringexample': 'some_string',
            'pathexample': plyer.storagepath.get_downloads_dir() 
    }
    
    def build(self):
        self.settings_cls = ScrollableSettings
        self.use_kivy_settings = False
        #setting = self.config.get('example', 'pathexample')
    
        return Interface()

    def build_config(self, config):
        config.setdefaults('example', self.default_settings)

    def build_settings(self, settings):
        settings.add_json_panel('Panel Name', self.config, data=settings_json)
        
    def on_config_change(self, config, section, key, value):
        print (config, section, key, value)

        if key == "configchangebuttons":
            # Reset config to defaults and write new vals 
            config.setall('example', self.default_settings)
            config.write()
            # Refreshes the settings menu to show that the default settings have been applied
            self.close_settings()
            self.destroy_settings()
            self.open_settings()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   SettingsApp().run()
```